# Line wrapping in select parts of buffer

Tags: org-mode, wrapping

When modifying an org buffer, is it possible to have line wrap selectively in different sections of the buffer?

I would to wrap my text outside code blocks. But inside the code blocks, we get some massive tokens that occupy the entire screen. Would it possible to disable word wrap for this section in particular?

[image: Example]

Comment: I think that this is more or less the same problem as: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/truncate-only-certain-lines-and-use-continuation-lines-elsewhere/19383#19383 You just formulated the question in the complementary way. Pityingly, the situation did not change with time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate only certain lines and use continuation lines elsewhere?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/truncate-only-certain-lines-and-use-continuation-lines-elsewhere)

Comment: It would be good for Someone (TM) to consolidate this question and those other two questions into a single Community question. The other two are posed only in specific contexts, which makes it hard to find them by searching for more general terms such as those expressed in this question.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I personally enable `word-wrap` and disable `truncate-lines` when narrowing to the subtree and do the reverse when widening again.