# How to include packages into my configuration?

Tags: spacemacs, package, config

a total newb when it comes to spacemacs. Firstly I just want to get spacemacs to work properly and I have the issues regarding the missing wrapping feature like in the following link ([Make visual-line-mode more compatible with org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7432/make-visual-line-mode-more-compatible-with-org-mode)). So now I tried out some things but I could not apply these packages easily in my config. Do I have to read the whole spacemacs layers documentation (http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html) for this now, or is there a more straight forward way to configure my editor (like I am used from vim)?

Comment: "So now I tried out some things but I could not apply these packages easily in my config." What did you try?  Exactly what problem(s) did you encounter?  At present your question is too vague.

Comment: Its not something worth mentioning in my opinion. I actually tried to  add the lines 'visual-line-mode' and 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode' in my user-config and in my layers section to the 'dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`-variable. In the layer section it threw an error, in the user section it just did nothing.

Comment: Don't explain your question in a comment: edit your question to make it understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for: Just add them to the `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` variable in `dotspacemacs/layers`.